# How can I detect if http request come from same client?

Tags: c++, sockets, http

I am making http/1.1 server for understanding better how webserver works.

I saw that http/1.1 version support "keep-alive" as default for network improvement, so I am trying to figure out how can I implement it...

For exemple, if client access one page, 
and send these two request (one for index.html for the first time, and other for favicon), my server make two socket per request regardless from which client.

```cpp
select(...);
FD_ISSET(fd, &read_set);
if (fd == server_socket)
{
    // here, i want to add code
    // if request come from same client and socket is still alive, 
    // I want to reuse it without creating new socket again.
    ...

    // else if request is another new client, then make connection 
    new_socket = accept(fd, (sockaddr *)&new_address, &new_len);
}
```

How can I detect if the client is same client or not ?
Thanks for reading.

Comment: Receiving multiple requests on the same socket, when keep alive is used, means absolutely nothing whatsoever regarding whether both requests came from the same client. It could very well be a proxy, proxying for multiple clients. If you want to maintain client state, that's what cookies are for.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. If i understand correctly, keep-alive doesn't mean the communication through same socket and actually more like a conception for proxy server ? @SamVarshavchik

Comment: No, keep-alive is communication of multiple HTTP requests through the same socket. Each individual request may come from the same or different clients. The fact that the requests come on the same socket is not related to anything.

Comment: `keep-alive is communication of multiple HTTP requests through the same socket.`
In this sentence, "same socket" means server socket ? not the client socket ? @SamVarshavchik

Comment: There's only one kind of socket out there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you mix two things: server socket is used to accept incoming connections. `new_socket` is used to read data from. If you want to handle `keep-alive` then you should not close the `new_socket` but wait for data on that socket using `select`

Comment: Thanks for answer :) But I am still lost. The problem is, second request from same client is treated as new incoming connection after going through select() even though i didn't close previous client socket.

Comment: @wpark It is entirely possible *and likely* that the client (a web browser? since a favicon is being requested) sends BOTH requests at the same time using different TCP connections.  Sure, HTTP 1.1 has keep-alives which allow multiple requests on a single TCP connection, but those requests will be handled *sequentially*. Handling requests *in parallel* requires either [multiple TCP connections](https://hpbn.co/http1x/#using-multiple-tcp-connections), or [HTTP/2 multiplexing](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/performance/http2#request_and_response_multiplexing).